# Select the row with the maximum date and other criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I know this question has been asked before and I have looked at heaps of solutions but I can't adapt any of the solutions to fit my problem.
I want to return the rows for each corporation and complianceTypeID that have the maximum date.

This Query shows my data.

```
    SELECT [ComplianceItemID]
      ,[CorporationID]
      ,[Date]
      ,[ComplianceTypeID]
  FROM [Compliance].[dbo].[ViewComplianceItem]
  Where CorporationID = '869'
```

Returns this result

```
ComplianceItemID    CorporationID       Date        ComplianceTypeID
55761               869                 2018-06-20  1
56840               869                 2022-11-07  2
57919               869                 1900-01-01  3
58998               869                 1900-01-01  4
60077               869                 1900-01-01  5
61156               869                 1900-01-01  6
62235               869                 1900-01-01  7
63316               869                 2018-06-25  8
63322               869                 2018-06-26  1
```

I only want to return the rows with the highest date within each ComplianceTypeID

I will later parameterize the query instead of a fixed CoprorationID.

I expect to see 8 rows returned, Row 1 should be excluded as there is another ComplianceTypeID 1 with a newer date.

I have tried this but only 5 rows are returned all with a date of '1900-01-01'

```
SELECT
    VC1.ComplianceItemID, 
    VC1.CorporationID, 
    VC1.[Date], 
    VC1.ComplianceTypeID 
FROM ViewComplianceItem VC1
Left Join ViewComplianceItem VC2 
    On VC1.ComplianceTypeID = VC2.ComplianceTypeID
    AND VC1.[Date] > VC2.[Date]
Where VC2.[Date] is null 
AND VC1.CorporationID = '869'
```

Result

```
ComplianceItemID    CorporationID       Date        ComplianceTypeID
57919               869                 1900-01-01  3
58998               869                 1900-01-01  4
60077               869                 1900-01-01  5
61156               869                 1900-01-01  6
62235               869                 1900-01-01  7
```

There seems to be many other approaches to solve this problem.
I only need one that works :)  I have been straining my brain for half the day and not progressing.

Thanks for any assistance
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually handled with a window function.

```
create procedure my proc (@corpID int)
as
begin

    ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        [ComplianceItemID]
        ,[CorporationID]
        ,[Date]
        ,[ComplianceTypeID]
        ,RN = row_number() over (partition by ComplianceTypeID order by [Date] desc)
    FROM [Compliance].[dbo].[ViewComplianceItem]
    WHERE CorporationID = @corpID)

    SELECT 
        [ComplianceItemID]
        ,[CorporationID]
        ,[Date]
        ,[ComplianceTypeID]
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1
end
```

You can also not do you parameterizaiton, or ignore the `WHERE` clause, and add it to the `PARTITION BY` to bring back your logic, for every corporation.

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
    [ComplianceItemID]
    ,[CorporationID]
    ,[Date]
    ,[ComplianceTypeID]
    ,RN = row_number() over (partition by CorporationID, ComplianceTypeID order by [Date] desc)
FROM [Compliance].[dbo].[ViewComplianceItem])

SELECT 
    [ComplianceItemID]
    ,[CorporationID]
    ,[Date]
    ,[ComplianceTypeID]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Lastly, this can also be handled with a derived table and the `MAX` aggregate:

```
SELECT 
    t1.[ComplianceItemID]
    ,t1.[CorporationID]
    ,t1.[Date]
    ,t1.[ComplianceTypeID]
FROM [Compliance].[dbo].[ViewComplianceItem] t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT CorporationID, ComplianceItemID, MAX([Date]) dt
            FROM [Compliance].[dbo].[ViewComplianceItem]
            GROUP BY CorporationID, ComplianceItemID) t2 on
            t2.CorporationID = t1.CorporationID 
            and t2.ComplianceItemID = t1.ComplianceItemID
            and t2.dt = t1.[Date]
```

Comment: @scismon,  Thanks for your detailed response the third option using a derived table didn't work.  It still returned all 9 rows.  The first two examples work but they introduce several new concepts that I don't understand.  How do I parameterize this so I can just select a single Corporation id?

Comment: I think I figured out a way to make it work.  I used your sql to create a view.  I should be able to create a parameterized query that reads data from the view.  Not the most elegant solution but I think it will work.  I'm not sure if you were suggesting I use your sql to create a function?  I'll test this tomorrow and mark your answer as correct once it works :)

Comment: I made an edit to show you how to do it with a proc.

Comment: I ended up going with the second one before I saw your update.  I created a view and then called the view from my c# program with SQL that included a where statement and my parameter for the corporation id.  It works exactly as I need.  I'm a self taught SQL'er so once it works I tend to stop looking.  I will however try to understand more about how your solution works.  Thanks very much for your assistance.